# use native integer data types to represent instruction and data words, rather than using dynamically allocated class-typed objects or strings

Tags: java, performance, oop, cpu-architecture

Who can explain to me what does the following sentance mean in java?

"In particular, you must use native integer data types to represent instruction and data
words, rather than using dynamically allocated class-typed objects or strings. Likewise, you should not attempt to represent
memory using a large array of words. Instead, consider a representation that allocates blocks of memory on
demand (that is, on the first read or write to an address within a block)."

Comment: What's the context of that passage and what exactly don't you understand about it?

Comment: It probably means you should use `final int ADD = 1` or `enum Instruction { ADD, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY, etc }` to represent instructions.

Comment: the whole paasage is "In particular, you must use native integer data types to represent instruction and data words, rather than using dynamically allocated class-typed objects or strings. Likewise, you should not attempt to represent memory using a large array of words. Instead, consider a representation that allocates blocks of memory on demand (that is, on the first read or write to an address within a block)."

Comment: It probably means that you're not allowed to use one array of integers (`int[]`) for your entire memory space, but that you should use some type of sparse array. Possibly using `int[][]` where each second level array is a fixed-size block of, say, 4096 integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others, I'm not very sure what it means. But working with [Java Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) allows you to store your

> represent instruction

in to the Stack memory. Maybe that is why this advice talks about String

> should not attempt to represent memory using a large array of words.

since it's implementation is *array of chars* and  by default have *overridden* `equals()` which actually compares Strings and not their references.

and

> rather than using dynamically allocated class-typed objects

For the reference types there are some complications that need to be considered first:

- when assigned, for references the object is not copied, it is shared (reference variables are aliases)
- when compared for references the contents of the objects are not compared
- assing Parameters for references the object is not copied, it is shared (i.e., actual parameter and formal parameter are aliases)
- returning values, locally created object can survive if it is returned or if it is stored in a data member

Here is visualization of the memory:

[image]

maybe this is a little simple explanation, but is all I can think from this quoted text, you've provide us.

Answer (score 0):

I think it refer to declare things like `int instruction = 2;` instead of `Instruction instruction = new Instruction4OpenFile()`.

But you need to give us more context.

Comment: the whole paasage is "In particular, you must use native integer data types to represent instruction and data words, rather than using dynamically allocated class-typed objects or strings. Likewise, you should not attempt to represent memory using a large array of words. Instead, consider a representation that allocates blocks of memory on demand (that is, on the first read or write to an address within a block)."

Comment: The "that allocates blocks of memory on demand" it seems to me like a List or a Map.